# Magento 1 - Error adding product to quote: This product is currently out of stock

Tags: magento-1, quote, stock

Trying to add product to a Quote and getting message that it is Out of Stock event though I set it to In Stock.  I have tried several things but here is the current code:

```
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', ['eq' => $item->sku]);
 $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product->getId());                    
 $stockItem->setIsInStock(true);      
 $stockItem->save();   
 $quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object(array('qty' => 1)));
```

Exception message is "This product is currently out of stock".

Here is a print_r of $product->getData() immediately before the addProduct() call.

```
Array
(
[entity_id] => 11093
[entity_type_id] => 4
[attribute_set_id] => 4
[type_id] => simple
[sku] => 150502
[has_options] => 0
[required_options] => 0
[created_at] => 2015-07-18 10:14:18
[updated_at] => 2018-01-03 18:26:56
[status] => 1
[visibility] => 4
[special_order] => 
[non_product] => 
[tax_class_id] => 2
[weight] => 0.0000
[price] => 36.4700
[group_price] => 
[image] => /1/5/150502.jpg
[small_image] => /1/5/150502.jpg
[thumbnail] => /1/5/150502.jpg
[name] => ME101
[part_no] => ME101
[item_no] => 150502
[meta_title] => ME101
[meta_description] => 
[options_container] => container1
[url_key] => me101
[url_path] => me101
[image_label] => ME101
[small_image_label] => ME101
[thumbnail_label] => ME101
[product_code] => 68
[special_from_date] => 
[short_description] => 
[description] => 
[parts_acc] => 
[ilm_tab] => 
[video] => 
[product_fields] => [{"type":799,"value":"MEC Brass"},{"type":45,"value":"1 1\/4\""},{"type":517,"value":"1\/2\" MNPT"},{"type":46,"value":"2 1\/2\""}]
[meta_keyword] => 
[stock_item] => Varien_Object Object
    (
        [_data:protected] => Array
            (
                [is_in_stock] => 
            )

        [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 
        [_origData:protected] => 
        [_idFieldName:protected] => 
        [_isDeleted:protected] => 
        [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
            (
            )

    )
```

)

Comment: check product status set to enable, product has quantity greater than 1 and is in stock

Comment: does the additional info above answer that?

Comment: @Black Can you please undo the edit? The question's tags already include "magento-1," so the title should not contain it. Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance no, this way we can already see in google that it is a magento 1 question and skip it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the answers [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62836/adding-product-to-cart-cause-error-the-stock-item-for-product-is-not-valid) solved my problem.  Had to reload the product with ->load() after getting the product id with ->loadByAttribute().

Answer (score 0):

I guess you also need to set the quantity. Magento checks both the "in stock" and the "qty" to determine if the product is in stock. Because there is also a setting "Qty for item's status to become out of stock" which is 0 by default. That makes that your product is not longer in stock.

Add `$stockItem->setQty(1);` to set the stock item quantity:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', ['eq' => $item->sku]);
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product->getId());
//Set stock quantity to 1
$stockItem->setQty(1);                    
$stockItem->setIsInStock(true);      
$stockItem->save();   
$quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object(array('qty' => 1)));
```

Comment: still getting "This product is currently out of stock".  Do I need to save the Product before I try to add it to the Quote?