# Magento 1.9 - How to add multiple products to cart at a time through add to cart Rest Api

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, rest-api

I need to forcefully add product Y to cart if product X is add to cart. Both X and Y are individual simple products. The following is what i have done to  achieve this:

```
try{
    $quote->assignCustomer($customer);
    $quote->addProduct($product, $request);
    $quote->collectTotals()->save();
    **if($productId==25)
    {
        $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $productCombo= $productModel->setStoreId($store)->loadByAttribute('sku','8903287005350');
        $param=$this->_getParam($productCombo,null,1);
        $request1 = new Varien_Object();
        $request1->setData($param);
        $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId($store)->loadByCustomer($customer);
        $quote->assignCustomer($customer);
        $quote->addProduct($productCombo, $request1);
        $quote->collectTotals()->save();
    }**
    $cartItems  = $this->_getCartItems($store,$quote->getData("entity_id"));
    $cart_data  = $this->getCartItemsData($store,$quote->getData("entity_id"));
    $message['status']              =   'success';                
    $message['message']             =   'Product successfully added to shopping cart';
    $message["quote_id"]            =   $quote->getData("entity_id");
    $message['cart_item_count']     =   $cart_data["cart_qty"];
    $message['grand_total']         =   $cart_data["grand_total"];
    $message['items']               =   $cartItems;
}
catch(Exception $e)
{                
    // $this->_critical("Product can't be added to shopping cart",Mage_Api2_Model_Server::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    $this->_critical($e);
}
```

And i am getting the following exception:

[image]

**NB: Both products X and y are in-stock, qty>10 and status=enabled**

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by the following method.

The Problem with my code was i was passing the wrong object to add to cart.
I was loading the product using loadByAttribute('sku',$_sku). The correct method  is to get the productId usign SKU and load product using load($productId).

ref: [Adding product to cart cause error 'The stock item for Product is not valid.'?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62836/adding-product-to-cart-cause-error-the-stock-item-for-product-is-not-valid)

So instead of

```
    $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $productCombo= $productModel->setStoreId($store)->loadByAttribute('sku','8903287005350');
```

I added

```
  $_sku = '8903287005350';
  $_catalog = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
  $_productId = $_catalog->getIdBySku($_sku);
  $productCombo = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($store)->load($_productId);
```

Answer (score 0):

How to adds multiple items to shopping cart, at a time?

Normally this code is kept into controller.

```
public function multipleProdAddAction()
      {
        $items = array("1" => "sku1" , "2" => "sku2");
        $invalidProduct = array();
        $validProducts = array();
        foreach($items as $qty=>$sku) {
            $id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);
            //Check whether the sku exists or not.
            if(!$id) {
                $invalidProduct[$sku] = $id;
            }
            else {
                $validProducts[$sku] = $quantity;
            }

        }
        //If any of the product we are adding, is not valid, we are not adding it to cart.
        if(count($invalidProduct) < 1 && count($validProducts) > 0) {
            try{
                $cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart();
                $ms="";
                foreach($validProducts as $sku => $qty) {
                    $params = array('qty' => $qty);
                    $id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);
                    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);;
                    $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
                    $msg .= $product->getName(). " is successfully added into cart<br>";
                }
                 $cart->save();
                 Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('checkout')->__($msg));
                 $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');

            }
            catch(Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('checkout')->__($e->getMessage()));
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
         }

        }  
      }
```

I hope it will help you.